# Copy specific words from Notepad ++

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, notepad++

I have a lot of text like this in Notepad:

[image]

and I want them to have like this:

[image]

I mean from all the document I only need to extract this thing...

<sub>BTW I AM NEW USER OF NOTEPAD++</sub>

Comment: If those are your current credentials, you should change them...NOW.

Answer (score 0):

Two steps:

1. [Delete all lines without text Credentials](https://superuser.com/questions/290247/delete-all-lines-in-notepad-except-lines-containing-a-word-i-need)
   Find: `^(?!Credentials - ).*\r\n`
   Replace: with nothing
   Regular Expressions: checked
2. Delete leading text "Credentials - "
   Find: `^Credentials -`
   Replace: with nothing
   Regular Expressions: checked